# JQuery Mobile Custom HTML in Page Loading Widget

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to have a custom HTML for Page Loading Widget for JQuery Mobile web app?

I tried the following:

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function(){
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all'><img src='/image/logo.png' /><h2>loading...</h2></span>";
});
```

But it still displays the default image. I want to have a global configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In single page

Documentation for the [loader available here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/loader/). Also check out this [documentation much relevant to you](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html).

You should do something as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.mobile.loading('show', {
    text: 'foo',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: "<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all'><img src='http://www.shougun.it/images/loading.gif' /><h2>loading...</h2></span>"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

### To setup as global

It needs to go belog `<script src=jquery.js>` but before `<script src=jquerymobile.js>` and must be called on`mobileinit` event.  Did you import the js before loading the jQuery Mobile js?

Comment: i want a global configuration